# Django and React.js Production

Tags: django, reactjs

When I've added a React to my Django project. It seems to be like everything works.
But if I refresh the page in the browser, I get an error:

[image]

I understand that Django is trying to find an appropriate view, but how to make it so that the React?

Comment: Adding the hash browser is probably the easiest way to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your server is catching routes that are meant for React and trying to handle them. You need to configure your routes so that only actual server routes are handled by the server (usually prefixed with `"/api/"`) and all others are handled by React.

Without seeing your `urls.py` file, I'm assuming you have your base/naked route (`"/"`) go to the React app, which works fine for initial requests (to the home page), but starts to break down when using a link or refreshing the page.

Your routing should basically use the React app in the way that 404 pages are usually used—when no matching routes on the server are found for the request. It's important that you define all other routes above the route to the React app, so that anything that the server knows how to handle is handled by the server, while the rest is passed along to React client.

So your urls should look something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^api/v1/", include("api_v1.urls", namespace="api_v1")),
    url(r"^.*", TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html")),
]
```

Where `index.html` is that of your React app.

Comment: This works, but then I cannot access the static server files, for example, to get avatars. Can I somehow exclude some links?

Comment: @CoderBug any URLs you define *above* the one for `index.html` will work fine, note that with this set up we basically treat the React app as the default case and only use it if nothing else has matched yet. So you could define a url for `"^static/"` or similar before the one for the React app and it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly an Apache/NGINX (front-end web server) configuration.

You should configure it to serve the same Django view, where you included your React source, for every route used by your React app.

An nginx example:

```
location ~ ^/your-django-view/?(.*) {
    # rewrite ^ index.html;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    break;
}
```

127.0.0.1:8000 should be changes with your django host:port.

Comment: I just added `re_path` to my `urls.py` in Django project)) Thanks!